# Jquery, using value of a variable inside a function, to set the value of another variable out side of that function

Tags: jquery, variables

I've abstracted and isolated a chunk of code I've written in a jquery plugin I'm creating.  In this code, the variable 'selector' in the loop has a value of 'rotator'.  I'd like to use that variable's value to set the value of the variable rotator declared outside of the loop.  I had tried using window, but obviously that doesn't work.  How would you go about doing this?

Thanks for any help on this, I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) { 
    $.fn.plugin_name = function( options ) { 

        var rotator;

        for ( var selector in selectors ) {
            window[selector] = selector_obj;   
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The question your asking and the code sample given don't seem to make sense. how is `selectors` defined? What id `selector_obj`? and what are you doing with the variable `rotator`. Also why the need to a global `window[selector]`? Since this is a jQuery plugin you could save the state in the closure created by the IIFE you demonstrated.

Comment: sorry to be unclear.  I have several variables besides rotator, I was just trying to isolate an example.  the loop is going through an object literal.  I was really just trying to isolate a specific example to see if it could be done.  If selector has the value rotate, how can I use that variable value to give the var rotator a value in the loop, in this case 'selector_obj'.

Comment: window doesn't work, I was just trying to give an example of what I had tried, and that it didn't work.  My feeling was there was something similar I could do along the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access the inner scope of your function (if not bind to an object). As is, I would suggest to put your `rorator` variables into an object, for instance here called `collection`, which you can easily access:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) { 
  $.fn.plugin_name = function( options ) {
      var collection = {};
      collection.rotator = ...;

      for ( var selector in selectors ) {
          collection[selector] = selector_obj;   
      }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: okay, I had considered doing this, but was really just wondering if there was a way to do it with variables in the inner scope.  That's really what I was asking, guess I wasn't super clear about it.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That was actually a good question. Scoping is obscure for many people, especially regarding `this`. Feel free to read about it if you want to learn more: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Comment: thanks man, I was getting confused with inner scope vs global.  Thanks for the link and the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can defined your rotator variable inside the outer function:

```
(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) { 
    var rotator;

    $.fn.plugin_name = function( options ) { 
        for ( var selector in selectors ) {
            // use rotator here
            window[selector] = selector_obj;   
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: so there a way to define it with out moving it into the global function?

Comment: Your variable(s) should be defined inside your function. If you keep them in the outer function, they will have "global" scope.

Comment: but wouldn't keeping var rotator inside $.fn.plugin_name = function( options ) { function be better?  The var rotator is part of the plugin, why would it get moved out side of it?

Comment: Global = out function of your plugin.